# How to export performance results from MATLAB Classification Learner?

Tags: matlab, statistics

The Classification Learner App provides nice results in the form of Confusion matricies, ROC curves etc in the App's GUI.

But how can all these values (e.g. accuracy, number of observations, TPP, FNR, PPV and FDR for all classes) be exported easily out of the App?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/export-classification-model-for-use-with-new-data.html

Comment: That's not what I was asking. Exporting a model is clear. How to export it's performance is the problem! Especially when many models are trained and I want to compare their performances.

Comment: Try to also look at [`confusionmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/confusionmat.html) and [`plotconfusion`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/plotconfusion.html) for the confusion matrix. And for the ROC you can try [`plotroc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/plotroc.html). But this are all options that are not included in the Classification Learner App directly.

Comment: Then what's the point of the App if I have to redo this outside of it? The numbers are caclulated inside the App, but remain unexportable unless you copy them by hand or call again these commands!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no simple GUI option for that in the classifier, but you can use some other functions to get the result. Here is one example:

**ROC curve:**

```
% load some sample data
fishertable = readtable('fisheriris.csv');
% here FisherClassifier is the exported code from the Classification
% Learner:
[trainedClassifier, validationAccuracy,validationPredictions,...
    validationScores] = FisherClassifier(fishertable);
% Species is the right classification:
species = fishertable.Species;
spp = 'versicolor'; % this is the species that you want it's ROC curve
% find the group number for this class:
cls = strcmp(spp,trainedClassifier.ClassificationKNN.ClassNames);
% calculate the ROC:
[X,Y,T,AUC] = perfcurve(species,validationScores(:,cls),spp);
% Plot it:
plot(X,Y,'LineWidth',2)
hold on
area(X,Y,'FaceColor',lines(1),'FaceAlpha',0.2)
xlabel('False positive rate')
ylabel('True positive rate')
text(0.5,0.5,['AUC = ' num2str(AUC)])
hold off
```

The result:

[image: ROC]

However, as can be read in [this answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/231614-how-can-i-copy-and-paste-figures-from-classification-learner) you can get all open figures handles by:

```
hFigs = findall(groot,'type','figure')
```

This will result in an array of figures, like this (for example):

```
hFigs = 
  4x1 Figure array:

  Figure    (MLearnAppConfusionMatrixFigure)
  Figure    (ParallelCoordinatesFigure)
  Figure    (MLearnAppROCCurveFigure)
  Figure    (ScatterFigure)
```

Now you can save them all to one `.fig` file (here called `allcalss`) using:

```
savefig(hFigs,'allcalss')
```

or save the one you want, say the Confusion Matrix by its specific handle:

```
savefig(hFigs(1),'confmat')
```

later you can poen them using the [`openfig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/openfig.html) command.

Comment: Thanks, but this is still not what I want, maybe I didn't explain it well. I do not what to export the actual **figures**, but the **numbers** given in say the confusion matrix. Yes, separate commands can be used, but then what's the point in training many classiiers in the GUI _simultaneously_, when one has to repeat the same outside of the GUI to get the performance out? Very week point of the App!

Comment: @ElenaRanguelova I think this is a dead end :( The "assumption" behind the app is that after you train all your models you"ll choose the best one and continue with it, so there is no simple option for export it all at once. You can write MathWorks about that and may see it in future versions. Sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Classification Learner App figure and choose `show code`.
Once a code is generated, run it. You will get another figure where you will see the same results.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for your contribution. However, this is quite a minimal answer bordering on being a comment. It could be improved with some helpful screenshots for example. In future, please use complete words, not mobile-phone-speak. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)